# Instert data in two tables with relation Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, insert

I want to insert with a form into two tables that are related with a foreign key,

First you need to create an order with customername, and then be forwarded to next form to insert multiple articles.

This is how my tables are made:

```
Schema::create('returnorders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firmaname');
            $table->string('contacperson');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('ordernumber');
            $table->string('customername');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('returnarticles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('returnorders');
            $table->string('articlenumber');
            $table->string('return_quantity');
            $table->string('return_quality');
            $table->string('return_reason');
            $table->string('images');
        });
```

My question is now, can i make one form where i can put multiple articles or should I make two forms, and that you will be forwarded from the first one to the next one?

My second question is, can I do this in one function in my controller or should i make two functions?

Help me out please, and if it's possible show me how to make my function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to save these related models, then you should look at the documentation on Inserting and Updating related models:

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Your code could look something like this:

```
$returnOrder = ReturnOrder::create([
   'firmaname' => $validatedInput['firmaname'],
   'contactperson' => $validatedInput['contactperson'],
   ....
]);

$returnOrder->returnArticles()->save(ReturnArticle::create([
   'articlenumber' => $validatedInput['articleNumber'],
   ...
]));
```